# Extjs 6 remote Store grouping not correctly

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs-grid

[image]Extjs grid when 'remoteSort: true' than grouping is wrong. and when I set 'remoteSort: false' it works fine
what seems to be the problem

here is a little code
that is grid feature

```
features: [
    {
        ftype: 'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: [
            '{columnName} : {name} ({rows.length} Item{[values.rows.length > 1 ? "s" : ""]})'
        ]
    }
],
```

and that is store

```
list: {
        remoteSort: true,
        pageSize: 50,
        model: 'List',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/records/load',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    }
```

and on button click

```
onGroupSubtypeClick: function(item, e, eOpts) {
    var store = this.getViewModel().getStore('list');
    store.group('level1Name');
},
```

Comment: Wrong in what aspect?

Comment: What data are you sending back? Are you sending it in the correct order?

Comment: Wrong in the picture, look at the grouping, Shouldn't it be `Medical Equipment` all in one group

Comment: and i am sending the same data nothing is changing

Comment: I don't know, you didn't post the data. Also it doesn't show how you're grouping the store.

Comment: edited my question,

Comment: You may need to add a sorters config to the store.  Maybe something like: `sorters:[
    { 
        property:'level1Name',         
        direction:'DESC'
    }
]`